# recursive function return using block not working

Tags: recursion, return, elisp

**[solved]**

I have something similar with these four functions: `base`, `init`, `func` and `some`. The `func` is recursive and calls itself: in the *"stop case"* it would call `some` and return its value, then it **should** return control back to "`init`", wherefrom it is invoked; the latter being once called from `base`.

```
base
  -> init
       -> func
            -> init
                 -> func
                      -> some
                    |
           _________+
          |
          v
          ; should continue from here (in `func`)
```

**[not anymore]**

Instead, after the first call to `some`, the control is yielded directly to `base`, skipping what I would expect to be the intermediate `(init,func)` pair call(s).

I actually tried several simpler cases using `block`, `return` and recursion (e.g., "mutual tail-recursive `factorial`"), and all worked well. I mention that `func` uses a `test` helper function that `catch` a `throw` (but I tried even an example with `(catch 'test (throw 'test 0))`, and it was ok); just so whatever could my real program have something causing the issue.

This is `elisp`: each `defun` commences with `block`, and all functions use `return`, as in the following.

**[I switched from using "`defun`/`block`" to "`defun*`"]**

```
(defmacro 4+ (number)
  "Add 4 to NUMBER, where NUMBER is a number."
  (list 'setq number (list '1+ (list '1+ (list '1+ (list '1+ number))))))

(defmacro 4- (number)
  "Subtract 4 from NUMBER, where NUMBER is a number."
  (list 'setq number (list '1- (list '1- (list '1- (list '1- number))))))

(defun mesg (s &optional o)
  "Use ATAB to tabulate message S at 4-multiple column; next/prev tab if O=1/0."
  (when (null o) (setq o 0))
  (case o (0 (4- atab)) (1 nil))
  (message (concat "%" (format "%d" (+ atab (length s))) "s") s)
  (case o (0 nil) (1 (4+ atab))))

(defun* base ()
  (let (pack)
    (setq atab 0)
    (mesg "base->" 1)
    (setq pack (init))
    (mesg "<-base")))

(defun* init ()
  (mesg "init->" 1)
  (return-from init (progn (setq temp (func)) (mesg "<-init") temp)))

(defun* func (&optional pack)
  (mesg "func->" 1)
  (when (not (null pack)) (return-from func (progn (mesg "<+func") pack)))
  (when (< 0 (mod (random) 2)); stop case
    (return-from func (progn (setq temp (some)) (mesg "<-func") temp)))
  (setq pack (init))
  (case (mod (random) 2)
    (0 (return-from func (progn (mesg "<0func") pack)))
    (1 (return-from func (progn (setq temp (func pack)) (mesg "<1func") temp))) ; use tail-recursion instead of `while'
    (t (error "foo bar"))))

(defun* some ()
  (mesg "some->" 1)
  (return-from some (progn (mesg "<-some") (list 2 3 4))))

(base)
```

The `pack` variable is my value-`list` as data structure. I also use `func` to reiterate itself (in tail-recursive call) with a special accumulating-parameter so that I avoid *"imperative"* `while`.

So instead of what I would expect (each `>` is paired by `<`)

```
base->
    init->
        func->
            init->
                func->
                    some->
                    <-some
                <-func
            <-init
            func-> ; tail-recursion
            <+func
        <1func
    <-init
<-base
```

my program behaves as follows.

```
base
  -> init
       -> func
            -> init
                 -> func
                      -> some
                           |
 __________________________+
|
v
; control yielded here (to `base`)
```

**[not anymore]**

Why is the control yielded *too soon* back to the start of the program, and not continue in the first call to `func`, after `return` from the second call via `init`?

Appreciate any help,

Sebastian

Comment: sorry, i put `some` now.

Comment: @Stefan: in other words, have there been some previously encountered functions/parts/questions *known* of [e]lisp that could possibly have *the least* interaction with `block`/`return` technique? (i.e., the function `string-match` ...?). I have the code in a public repository, but to the end purpose i'm at only 20%, and it has to do with parsing `LaTeX` code lines).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it is not clear to me what's the extent of the block in `func`. If the block includes the whole `func` definition, then yes, the control reaches `func` when returning, but the block is skipped completely, hence the function completely, and comes back all the way up where it was called (eventually `base`). May be that the case?

If that's so, you have to put the code that you want to execute after a return after the block.

**EDIT**: Looking again at your code, I think you're not using the `return` as it should be used. For instance in `init` you have

```
(block nil
 ...

 (return (func ...)))
```

This `return` "cancels" the block, and takes the same effect as not having the block at all, *unless* some function called in "`...`" does have a `return` *without* a `block`. So the `return` here cancels the possible return points of `func`.

Comment: I mean that `block` wraps all other code, including any [unconditioned] `return` and conditioned `return` "points", and so cancels the rest, but not that `block` represents the value returned by the `defun`, a present one, not phantom.

Comment: What exactly you mean? All `return` points from inside the same `defun`/`block` exclude one another in what way?

Comment: I reread your answer. You are right, but the case is that `block` extent wraps all function body, that is, it is the "only function" as far as elisp interpreter is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks both for your answer: inserting into my program those messages I tried as with the code I added for explanations revealed there are no `defun*` problems with `elisp`, but some things I mistook in design.